# What should the general backend process be when a customer places an order on the front end when working with stripe / paypal

Tags: node.js, paypal, stripe-payments

I am currently building an ecommerce website with Next.js and have utilized Stripe's and Paypal's react library for my checkout. I am wanting to know how I should handle posting the order information to my database. I currently have a webhook endpoint setup for Stripe but I have realized that I am not able to recieve any order details in the webhook.

An approach I thought about was posting all of the order information to my orders table even though it hasn't been confirmed and also storing the paypal / stripe id. Once I recieve the webhook I can then mark the order as confirmed. With this approach I realize that anyone could post an order to the database through the API route, but it wouldn't ever get confirmed because there wouldn't be any webhook that gets triggered. Is this approach optimal or is there a better way of posting orders to a database?

I have my stripe payments set-up exactly as shown in this guide: https://stripe.com/docs/payments/quickstart where once the user clicks the checkout page, a payment intent is created on the backend and the client secret is sent to the front-end. I then have a webhook setup specifcally for successful payments where I verify that the request came from stripe.

Comment: "*I am not able to recieve any order details in the webhook*" - you can include metadata when creating they payment intent, which can include anything, eg the order id. You can access that when handling the webhook, and retrieve the associated order. Regarding orders created and not confirmed - this can and will happen even from legitimate customers who don't complete their orders, due to credit card problems, customers changing their minds, customers losing network access, anything. You might set up a process which clears unconfirmed orders from the DB after some period to handle these.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the PayPal checkout, you don't need webhooks for normal processing. Use the v2/checkout/orders API and make two routes (url paths) on your server, one for 'Create Order' and one for 'Capture Order'. You could use the (recently deprecated) @paypal/checkout-server-sdk for the routes' API calls to PayPal, or your own HTTPS implementation of first getting an access token and then doing the call. Both of these routes should return/output **only** JSON data (no HTML or text). Inside the 2nd route, when the capture API is successful you should verify the amount was correct and store its resulting payment details in your database (particularly `purchase_units[0].payments.captures[0].id`, which is the PayPal transaction ID) and perform any necessary business logic (such as reserving product or sending an email) immediately *before* forwarding return JSON to the frontend caller. In the event of an error forward the JSON details of it as well, since the frontend must handle such cases.

Pair those 2 routes with this frontend approval flow: https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/server .  (If you need to send any additional data from the client to the server, such as an items array or selected options, add a `body` parameter to the fetch with a value that is a JSON string or object. Your server can verify the information is correct before doing anything with it.)

---

You can load the frontend JS with @paypal/paypal-js if desired , or just a normal script tag

Comment: This seems exactly like what I was looking for, my main concern was that anyone could call the API and falsely create an order. Just to clarify, by sending the orderId in the API URL ('/demo/checkout/api/paypal/order/' + data.orderID + '/capture/'), the backend can first verify the orderId before creating the order which would prevent people from creating false orders because they wouldn't be able to supply a valid id, is this correct?

Comment: The capture route does not create PayPal orders. As for your own order record, only mark one as paid when a capture is successful and for the correct amount.